# Injective but not surjective R-module homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, ring-homomorphism, free-modules

Let $R$ be a PID.

I want to find an injective but not surjective $R$-module homomorphism $\varphi:R^n\to R^n$ for some $n\geq 1$.

I can find injective but not surjective ring homomorphism (for $n=1$). For example, we can take $F$ as a field and consider $R=F[x]$. We can define $f:F[x]\to F[x]$ by letting $f(a)=a$ for all $a\in F$ and $f(x)=x^2$, where this example was given by @egreg, cf. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/617680/507382).

By when we take the $R$-module structure (or the scalar multiplication) into account, the ring homomorphism $f$ defined above is no longer a $R$-module homomorphism.

Can someone give me an example or tell me how to modify the $f$ above such that it becomes an $R$-module homomorphism? Thanks for help.

Comment: Hint: if $R=\mathbb Z$, then what does $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(\mathbb Z,\mathbb Z)$ look like?

Comment: This will not work for every PID. Fields have to be excluded. And this already shows you how to start ... take any non-zero non-invertible element.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I confused myself with the definition of module homomorphism... which doesn't have to be a ring homomorphism (i.e. preserving multiplication) because a module only has an addition structure... Thanks again..

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Hi Martin, if possible, can you take a look at the question I proposed under the answer of Sammy? Thanks. That's actually the problem I had in mind at the very beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are already examples for $n=1$, i.e. the *regular module* over $R$. Since you want your map $\varphi: R \to R$ to be $R$-linear (this is another way of saying that $\varphi$ is an $R$-module homomorphism), the map is completely determined by where you send $1$:
$$
\varphi(r) = \varphi(r \cdot 1) = r \,\varphi(1). 
$$

Some immediate examples where $\varphi$ is injective but not surjective:

1. For a field $F$, so that $R = F[x]$ is a PID, and any $d \in \mathbb{N}$,
   $$
   \varphi: F[x] \to F[x], 
   \qquad 
   1 \mapsto x^d
   $$
2. For $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and any $n \neq 0$,
   $$
   \varphi: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}, 
   \qquad 
   1 \mapsto n
   $$
3. For $R = \mathbb{Z}/m$ and any $n \in \bigl( \mathbb{Z}/m \bigr)^\times$, i.e. $\gcd(m, n) = 1$,
   $$
   \varphi: \mathbb{Z}/m \to \mathbb{Z}/m, 
   \qquad 
   1 \mapsto n
   $$

Comment: Hi Sammy, thanks for the answer. I have a question about your third example. Let us consider $m=6$ and $n=5$. It seems like $\varphi$ is a bijection?

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're right. I wrote that too quickly. Examples in class (3) will always be bijections. In fact, using cardinality arguments, if $R$ is finite, then injective necessarily implies surjective.

Comment: Yea that's true. No worries. Thanks for your remaining two quick examples.

Comment: Can I ask one more question? Suppose we have a PID ring $R$ and think $R^n$ as an $R$-module. Is there an injective $R$-module homomorphism from $R^n$ to $R^n$, which is not subjective and preserves the multiplication structure on $R^n$? (This is actually the original problem I had in mind because I confused myself with the definition of $R$-module homomorphism...). Thanks!

Comment: What is the multiplication structure on $R^n$? It's not a ring. It's useful to remember that $R$-module generalizes $F$-vector space for when the scalars are not necessarily a field.

Comment: Hmmm, can we define $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_n)\cdot (b_1, b_2, ..., b_n):=(a_1 b_1, a_2 b_2, ..., a_n b_n)$ via the multiplication structure on $R$ since $R^n=\bigoplus_n R$? (To be honest, I am not sure about the definition of the notation $R^n$...)

Comment: You *can* define a multiplication map $R^n \times R^n \to R^n$ that way, and it will have lots of nice properties, leading to the notion of an $R$-algebra **but** that's all in addition to the underlying module structure. All you have in a module is a collection of "vectors" that you form $R$-linear combinations with.

Comment: It might be useful to use a different notation for a scalar $r \in R$ and vector $(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in X^n$. It happens to be the case that we're using the $X=R$ to define these vectors, but we don't retain the multiplication or think of $X$ as a ring anymore. Think of the roles of scalars $\mathbb{R}$ in the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$.